# PLS-00103 encoutered the symbol

Tags: sql, oracle

I already tried to look for this type of error. I do have similar errors on others but different problems. Please help me with this, what is the good approach to this sample oracle query ?

```
create type Exams (
    year char(4),
    city varchar(20)
)
create table exams of type Exams 

create OR REPLACE type Skills AS OBJECT(
type varchar(20),
ExamSet Exams multiset
);
/
create table skills of Skills;
```

Here is the error in script output :

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
1/12      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     ; is authid as compress force compiled wrapped under 
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: use the semicolon ; to terminate each statement. look up the `CREATE TYPE` [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375), is seems to need one of the keywords AS or IS or UNDER before the opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ExamsType AS OBJECT ( 
    year char(4),
    city varchar(20) 
);
/
create table Exams OF ExamsType;
```

Fixes :

- create the type `AS OBJECT` ; this will give you an Abstract Data Type (ADT), that can actually hold attributes - see [the oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#i2083561)
- you need a semi-colon and a slash at the end of the `create type` statement
- the table cannot have the same name as the type
- syntax for `CREATE TABLE` was wrong

To insert in this table, you would typically use the following statement :

```
insert into Exams values( ExamsType('2018', 'my adress') );
```

Comment: Thanks!! Just to add on it if its okay i'll add it above

Comment: Welcome @Quequequee !

Comment: I just added a last one with "multiset" thing. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT *
      FROM old_table WHERE 1=2);
```

For your case it goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE exams 
  AS (SELECT *
      FROM Exams WHERE 1=2);
```

for `1=2` it does not select any of the rows but with `as` it copies the table definition.